# Thymeleaf How can I display a column from one table based on a value from another table

Tags: mysql, thymeleaf

I'm working on a small project trying to learn thymeleaf.
I have 3 tables Timetables which contains an id, assignment id as a foreign key and other stuff, Assignments which contains and id and project id as a foreign key and Projects which contains and id and project name.

I need to display Timetables in an html, easy enough, however i want to display the project name instead of the assignment id column.

I already have a select in my service class which calls the required columns but how can i tell thymeleaf to read that column instead of looking for it in Timetables.

Here is my code

html

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>assignment</th>
        <th>date</th>
        <th>number of hours</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="timetable: ${timetables}">
        <td th:text="${timetable.timetableId}">45</td>
        <td th:text="${timetable.assignmentId}">vasi</td>
        <td th:text="${timetable.date}">1 ian</td>
        <td th:text="${timetable.hoursWorked}">3000</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Service class

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate template;

public List<Timetable> findAll(String loginname) {
    String sql = "  SELECT timetables.timetableId, timetables.assignmentId, timetables.date, timetables.hoursWorked, users.username, projects.projectName FROM timetables INNER join assignments on assignments.assignmentId = timetables.assignmentId INNER JOIN users on users.userId = assignments.userId " +
            "INNER JOIN projects on assignments.projectId = projects.projectId where username= ?";

    RowMapper<Timetable> rm = new RowMapper<Timetable>() {
        @Override
        public Timetable mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
            Timetable timetable = new Timetable(resultSet.getInt("timetableId"),
                    resultSet.getInt("assignmentId"),
                    resultSet.getDate("date"),
                    resultSet.getInt("hoursWorked"));

            return timetable;
        }
    };

    return template.query(sql, rm, loginname);
}
```

Controller

```
@Autowired
TimetableService service;

@Autowired
AssignmentsService serv;

@RequestMapping(value = {"/Timetable"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Model md) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String loginname = auth.getName();
    md.addAttribute("timetables", service.findAll(loginname));
    return "Timetable";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with JdbcTemplate but I whink you need to do the following

add the projectName in the Timetable class if you do not have it already and in the mapRow

```
RowMapper<Timetable> rm = new RowMapper<Timetable>() {
        @Override
        public Timetable mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
            Timetable timetable = new Timetable(resultSet.getInt("timetableId"),
                    resultSet.getInt("assignmentId"),
                    resultSet.getDate("date"),
                    resultSet.getString("projectName"),
                    resultSet.getInt("hoursWorked"));

            return timetable;
        }
    };
```

Then, in the html page add the projectname as well

```
<tbody>
   <tr th:each = "timetable: ${timetables}">
         <td th:text="${timetable.timetableId}">45</td>
         <td th:text="${timetable.projectName}">vasi</td>
         <td th:text="${timetable.date}">1 ian</td>
         <td th:text="${timetable.hoursWorked}">3000</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much.

For future reference besides the above I needed a field in my model class called projects, getter and setter for it and another constructor which used string project instead of assignmentId